# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS Background

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I have been working on ros for a few months now. I wish to know the basic building philosophy and the design of ROS to be able to

1. understand why / hows of ROS
2. to become a better programmer as such.

Is there anything online (I couldn't find any) which gives the very base level design structure in complete detail. I could go through the code and I have been doing that but any documentation on that would be quite helpful .

Thanks.
Neeraj

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28103/ros-background/) by [navderm](https://answers.ros.org/users/984/navderm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend going through the [Start Guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/StartGuide) It includes how to get started as well as a [technical overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Introduction).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3